# Spectral decomposition of a C$^*$algebra with respect to an action of a compact abelian group

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact abelian group (finite dimensional, but not finite) and $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Consider an action $\alpha: G\to Aut(A)$. In analogy with the case of finite abelian group, I believe that it is true that $A=\oplus_{\chi\in \hat{G}} A_\chi$, with $A_\chi$ being the subspace made of elements $x\in A$ such that $\alpha_g(x)=\chi(g)x$. Moreover, I think that there exist a family of linear maps (indexed by the characters of the group)  $E_\chi: A\to A_\chi$
$$
E_\chi(x)=\int_G \overline{\chi(g)}\alpha_g(x) 
$$
Can someone tell me if it is true and give me reference to a book or paper? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't have a copy on hand, but surely this is covered in Pedersen, C*-Algebras and Their Automorphism Groups.

Comment: I have worked out the details of this for the case of the circle group in "Circle actions on C*-algebras, partial automorphisms and a generalized Pimsner-Voiculescu exact sequence", J. Funct. Analysis, 122 (1994), 361-401.  The computations easily generalize to compact abelian groups.  Moreover I have worked a bit on this problem in the case of actions of non-compact abelian groups in "Morita-Rieffel equivalence and spectral theory for integrable automorphism groups of C*-algebras", J. Funct. Analysis, 172 (2000), 404-465.

Comment: You need to put $\overline{\chi}$ instead of $\chi$ in the integral (so that one gets the identity on $A_{\chi}$ !).

Comment: @ Ruy: Thank you much for the references. The papers contain the answer to the particular case of the circle and I appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: @: Simon Henry: Thank you! I corrected the formula.

Comment: @Nik Weaver: Thanks for the reference! I'll look try to look at the book as soon as I'll go to the library.

Comment: @John, this is just a small point regarding the workings of Mathoverflow.  If you mention someone by name in a comment, preceeding the person's name by the character "@", that person is alerted about it.  But this only works if there is no space between the "@" and the name, which you inadvertently inserted twice above.

Comment: @Ruy: Thanks for the information. I did't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facts that $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and that $G$ is abelian are irrelevant: such a decomposition holds more generally for any Banach space $A$ with a continuous linear action of a compact group. The reference I know for this is *Representations of a compact group on a Banach space* by Shiga, available 
[here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1261414131). There are probably earlier references for abelian groups, but I do not know them.

Comment: @JohnN. : to be more precise, I am not sure whether the formula for the projection $E_\chi$ appears explicitely in Shiga's paper. Anyway, I needed the result and I reproved it in Theorem 2.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2475